# $X$ a normal r.v , calculating $\mathbb{E}(e^{\lambda X})$

Tags: normal-distribution, solution-verification, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

$X\sim { \mathcal{N}( \mu , \sigma^2) } $ 
a normal r.v,  $Y = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} $

The solution says $\mathbb{E}(e^{\lambda X})= \mathbb{E}(e^{\sigma \lambda Y}) e^{\lambda \mu} = e^{\sigma^2 \lambda^2 + \lambda \mu} $

But what I find is :

$\mathbb{E}(e^{\lambda X}) = e^{ \frac{ \sigma^2 \lambda^2}{2} + \lambda \mu} $

I can't see that I made a calculation mistake:

$ \mathbb{E}( \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} ) = \int y \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-y^2/2} $ which gives $Y$ ~ ${ \mathcal{N}( 0 , 1) } $

$ \mathbb{E}(e^{ \lambda Y} ) = \int e^{\lambda y} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-y^2/2} = e^{\lambda^2/2} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-(y-\lambda)^2/2} = e^{\lambda^2/2}$

Now for $e^{\lambda X}$:

$ \mathbb{E}(e^{ \lambda X} ) = \mathbb{E}(e^{ \lambda \sigma Y + \mu \lambda} ) $
$= e^{\lambda \mu}\mathbb{E}(e^{ \lambda \sigma Y } ) 
$
$= e^{\lambda \mu} \int e^{\lambda \sigma y } \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-y^2/2} $

$= e^{\lambda \mu + \mu ^2\lambda^2/2} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-(y-\sigma \lambda)^2/2} = e^{\lambda \mu + \mu ^2\lambda^2/2}$

EDIT : I made a typing mistake, I meant :

$= e^{\lambda \mu + \sigma ^2\lambda^2/2} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-(y-\sigma \lambda)^2/2} = e^{\lambda \mu + \sigma ^2\lambda^2/2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last two equalities are wrong. Note that $\lambda \sigma y-y^{2}/2=-(y-\lambda \sigma )^{2}/2+\lambda ^{2} \sigma ^{2}/2$.

EDIT: Your edited answer is correct and the given answer is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I made a typing mistake yes I meant :

$= e^{\lambda \mu + \sigma ^2\lambda^2/2} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-(y-\sigma \lambda)^2/2} = e^{\lambda \mu + \sigma ^2\lambda^2/2}$

Comment: @Khan I have edited my answer.